# Django Factory for model with Generic Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, factory-boy, generic-foreign-key

I'm trying to write up a Factory for a model with a GFK for testing but I can't seem to get it working. I've referred to the [common recipes](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html) in the docs, but my models don't match up exactly, and I'm also running into an error. Here are my models

```
class Artwork(models.Model):
    ...
    region = models.ForeignKey("Region", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

class Region(models.Model):
    # Could be either BeaconRegion or SpaceRegion
    region_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    region_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    region = GenericForeignKey("region_content_type", "region_object_id")


class SpaceRegion(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    regions = GenericRelation(
        Region,
        content_type_field="region_content_type",
        object_id_field="region_object_id",
        related_query_name="space_region",
    )


class BeaconRegion(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    regions = GenericRelation(
        Region,
        content_type_field="region_content_type",
        object_id_field="region_object_id",
        related_query_name="beacon_region",
    )
```

Essentially, an `Artwork` can be placed in one of two `Region`s; a `SpaceRegion` or `BeaconRegion`.

I've created the following `Factory`s for the corresponding models

```
class RegionFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    region_object_id = factory.SelfAttribute("region.id")
    region_content_type = factory.LazyAttribute(
        lambda o: ContentType.objects.get_for_model(o.region)
    )

    class Meta:
        exclude = ["region"]
        abstract = True


class BeaconRegionFactory(RegionFactory):
    label = factory.Faker("sentence", nb_words=2)
    region = factory.SubFactory(RegionFactory)

    class Meta:
        model = Region


class SpaceRegionFactory(RegionFactory):
    label = factory.Faker("sentence", nb_words=2)
    region = factory.SubFactory(RegionFactory)

    class Meta:
        model = Region


class ArtworkFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    ...
    region = factory.SubFactory(SpaceRegionFactory)
```

In my test, I try to create an Artwork using `ArtworkFactory()`, but it errors with

```
AttributeError: The parameter 'region' is unknown. Evaluated attributes are {}, definitions are <DeclarationSet: {'region_object_id': <SelfAttribute('region.id', default=<class 'factory.declarations._UNSPECIFIED'>)>, 'region_content_type': <factory.declarations.LazyAttribute object at 0x1068cf430>, 'label': <factory.faker.Faker object at 0x1068cf880>}>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue comes when resolving `ArtworkFactory.region.region`, i.e `SpaceRegionFactory.region`.

From your models, it seems that:

- `Region` is a table which points to either `SpaceRegion` or `BeaconRegion`
- `SpaceRegion` and `BeaconRegion` are simple tables, with a helper to retrieve the related `Region` object.

The first step in those complex relation chains is to write the code without factories:

```py
>>> shire = SpaceRegion(label="Shire")
>>> shire_generic = Region(region=shire)
>>> the_ring = Artwork(region=shire_generic)
```

This tells us that the `Region` is always created after the `SpaceRegion` or `BeaconRegion`, giving the following factories:

```py
class SpaceRegionFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.SpaceRegion
    label = factory.Faker("sentence", n_words=2)


class RegionFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Region

    region = factory.SubFactory(SpaceRegionFactory)


class ArtworkFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Artwork

    region = factory.SubFactory(RegionFactory)
```

With this, you should be able to get your code working.
Note how we're simply setting the `region` field on `Region`: Django's internals will extract the object content type / content ID automatically.

### Additional options

You could tune the `RegionFactory` to let callers decide whether they want a `SpaceRegion` or a `BeaconRegion`:

```py
class RegionFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        models = Region

    class Params:
        space = True  # Request a SpaceRegion

    region = factory.Maybe(
        factory.SelfAttribute("space"),
        factory.SubFactory(SpaceRegion),
        factory.SubFactory(BeaconRegion),
    )
```

Comment: Amazing, this worked beautifully! Just a question on the `factory.Maybe()`; I'm guessing that `SpaceRegion` the default if nothing additional is passed. Is it possible to specify a `BeaconRegion` on another model as a SubFactory? How would one pass across the `space=False` kwarg? Since typically, a SubFactory would be defined as `region = factory.SubFactory(RegionFactory)`

Comment: @Andrew You could pass `factory.SubFactory(RegionFactory, space=False)`. Fields described in `class Params` are evaluated just like each other declaration, with the only exception that they don't get passed in to the underlying model: they are supposed to be parameters for the *factory*, exactly the role of `space=True` in this example ;)